# Evernote users in the application database

Tags: database, authentication, membership, evernote

What's the best practice or the common way of keeping (or not keeping) Evernote users in your application's database?

Should I create my own membership system and create a connection to Evernote accounts?

Should I store Evernote user data (or only part of it) in my own app and let the user log in only with Evernote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:** you must protect their data but *how* you protect it is up to you. Use the integer `edam_userId` to identify data.

I think the [API License agreement](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/api_license.php) covers protection in the terms:

*you agree that when using the API you will not, directly or indirectly, take or enable another to take any of the following actions:...
1.8.4 circumvent or modify any Keys or other security mechanism employed by Evernote or the API;*

If you cache people's data and your server-based app lacks security to prevent people looking at other's data, then I think you're pretty clearly violating that clause. I think it's quite elegantly written!

Couple that with the responsibility clause 1.2

*You are fully responsible for all activities that occur using your Keys, regardless of whether such activities are undertaken by you or a third party.*

So if you don't protect someone's cached data and another user is able to get at it, you're explicitly liable.

Having cleared up the question of your obligations to (as you'd expect) protect people's data, the question is how do you store it?

Clause 4.3 covers identifiers pretty directly although it's a bit out of date now that we are all forced to use oAuth - there are **no** passwords ever entered into anything other a web view. However, mobile or desktop client apps *must provide a mechanism for the user to log out, which must completely remove the username and password from your application and its persistent storage.*

For a web app, you can't even save the username: *If your Application runs as an Internet service on a multi-user server, you must not ask for, view, store or cache the sign-in name or password of Evernote user accounts.*

The good news is that you can rely on the `edam_userId` value which comes back to you in the oAuth token credentials response, as discussed [here](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Authentication.php).

When you look at the [Data Model](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Data_structure.php), you can see the unique id under the User and going into the [User struct](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Types.html#Struct_User), see the reassuring definition *The unique numeric identifier for the account, which will not change for the lifetime of the account.*

Thinking about the consequences, as you can't get the user id until you have logged into the service, if you want to provide a local login for people you will have to link your local credentials to the user id. That may irk some people if they have to enter a username twice but can't be helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow users to log-in via OAuth. Here's a [guide](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Authentication.php) on how that process works.

But you'll probably also want to store a minimal amount of user data, at least a unique identifier, in your database so you can do things like create relationships between the user and their notebooks and tags. Refer to the Evernote [data model](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/Data_structure.php) for those relationships. If you're using rails, this will also help you take advantage of rails conventions.